# Unable to boot simulator xcode 7.3.1 / OS 10.11.6

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I know similar questions have been asked many times.
My xcode projects ran fine on the simulator. Ive started a new project today and the first time I tried running it I get the black screen and 'unable to boot simulator error'.. and I have to force quit xcode. Now all my projects are getting the same error??? They were working fine before.. I have not updated anything either? Whats the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked out the other Q&As available when Googling `unable to boot simulator error`? Did nothing described there help?

Comment: yes of course I have.. I have a specific problem that I have not found anywhere by googling. I have not changed anything about my system (updates, settings etc).. This issue has only started since creating a new project, writing some code in a single view application and attempting to run it..

Comment: So nothing described in those other questions helped?

Comment: @pekka  Not really but please check my answer and thanks

Answer (score 1):

After many failed attempts at fixing the problem I ended up updating the OS from El Capitan to Sierra and I completely uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled a fresh version (from 7.3 to 8). The problem is now gone. I am assuming there was some kind corruption in Xcode as I cant figure how else this specific issue would occur.